# vba cope variable module

Tags: excel, vba, object, module, scope

when i change avalue in B2:B10 in need the message "update"
When running Insert_row it should not give that message.
The code works but when I place the procedure Insert_row in another module the public variable is not known ?
How can i solve this.

```
Public blockchange As Boolean

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B2:B10")) Is Nothing And blockchange = False Then
MsgBox "Update"
End If

End Sub

Sub Insert_rows()

blockchange = True
Dim LastRow As Integer

LastRow = 3 * ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
For i = 3 To LastRow Step 3
    Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Insert
    Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Insert
   
Next i
blockchange = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Declare it in a normal module.

Comment: Or use e.g. `Sheet1.blockchange` in the procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some thoughts:
**(1)** As SJR wrote, put global variables into a regular module.

**(2)** If you insist, you can have a global variable also in the code of the sheet. In this case you access it by putting the *codename* of the sheet as prefix, eg `Sheet1.blockchange`. The *codename* of a sheet is the internal name of a sheet, you see it in the VBA editor in the project window or if you open the property window (F4), it is displayed in the first row as `(name)`. This name doesn't change if a sheet is renamed, you can change it only in the VBA editor.

**(3)** For your specific case, it's maybe better not to use a variable but simply to prevent the events to fire while the `Insert`-code is running. You do this with the statement `Application.EnableEvents = False`. Just don't forget to put `Application.EnableEvents = True` at the end of the code, maybe with an error handler to prevent that the statement is not executed when an error occurs.

Comment: Yes, this is a better solution.